# Is there a practical way to view ext file system on Windows?

Tags: filesystems, partition, windows, ext4

I have a project which requires a lot of contact with ext file system. But the majority of tools is based on Windows. Thus is there any software or plugin for explorer which allow the access to ext on Windows?

Comment: I think this question is probably better posed on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes one method could be via third party software installed on your Windows computer such as outlined in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/141919/874967).
 However, I cannot vet for the authenticity of any Windows programs or whether they will compromise the integrity of your ext file system.

Another method, if your Windows System and Linux System are installed on separate systems as either Virtual Machines or on different hardware, would be to make a file share server using something like Samba or NFS to share access to the ext file system via the network.